# GetActiveNotifications returns null

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

I have a messenger application and now I'm doing push notifications part. I'm using `FCM` (Firebase Cloud Messaging)for this. Now I have a problem. For example introduce 2 users (user1 and user2). If user1 writes me, I'm getting notification with `FCM` and show it. When user2 writes me, I'm creating new notification for it. But when user1 writes me again and I don't removed my user1 notification, I need to update the notification, else create new. I think you understand me. Now I am stuck at update part, because every time I'm create a new notification on message income.

I searched and found something. It says I have to use `NotificationListenerService` for this and use `getActiveNotifications()` for getting all active notifications in status bar.

So I tried something, but I'm getting `null`. I enabled this application in Notification Access, so I think this is not the problem.
I registered my services in manifest file.

Here is my code, where I created my `FCM` service. If I done something wrong in my code, please fix it.

```
public class FireBaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FireBaseMessagingServiceTag";

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Handle FCM messages here.

    Intent service = new Intent(FireBaseService.this, NotificationService.class);
    startService(service);

    //I think I'm doing wrong here.
    NotificationService notificationService = new NotificationService();

    StatusBarNotification[] activeNotifications = notificationService.getActiveNotifications();

    Log.d(TAG, "Array: " + Arrays.toString(activeNotifications));

    //show notification
}
}
```

And here is the `NotificationService` class.

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onListenerConnected() {
    super.onListenerConnected();
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
    // Implement what you want here
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){
    // Implement what you want here
}

@Override
public StatusBarNotification[] getActiveNotifications() {
    return super.getActiveNotifications();
}
}
```

So this is all I done. Can you help me? Thank you and please fix my code, if I done something wrong instead of giving bad vote to my question.

Here is the notification part.

```
private void showNotification(String title, String body) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.fcmnotification.FireBaseService";

    if(notificationManager != null) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NotificationManager",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("My Channel");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("info");

        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the notification creating part ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `NotificationListenerService`. Just get the active notifications from the `NotificationManager`

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
StatusBarNotification[] statusNotifs = null;
try {
    statusNotifs = nm.getActiveNotifications();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // it can crash
}
if (statusNotifs != null) for (StatusBarNotification n : statusNotifs) {
    Notification notif = n.getNotification();
    try {
        String ntext = notif.extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT).toString();
        // do something
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // can crash
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear friend. The notificationmanager.getActiveNotifications() requires API 23 and higher. My min API is 18. Any idea?